# O que tem de errado na minha pilha dinâmica?

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer uma pilha dinâmica, e por algum motivo tem algo de errado na função `init`. Está dando o seguinte erro:

> warning: conflicting types for 'init'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct TipoCelular
{
    int elemento;
    struct TipoCelular *prox;
}elementoPilha;

typedef struct TipoTopo
{
    elementoPilha *Topo;
}Pilha;

int main()
{
    Pilha *p;

    init(p);

    if(empty(p))
        printf("Pilha vazia\n");

    return 0;
}

void init(Pilha *p)
{
    p->Topo = NULL;
}

int empty(Pilha *p)
{
    if(p->Topo == NULL)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É porque vc usou a função `init()` antes de ela ser definida.

Coloque a definição dela antes da função `main` ou deixe onde ela está e adicione apenas o protótipo dela antes da `main`.

```
void init(Pilha *p);
/* ... */
```

Comment: Declarei os protótipos, mas ao compilar dá:  .exe parou de funcionar.

Comment: Agora que percebi. O `*p` no seu `main`  não é uma `Pilha`, é um ponteiro apenas. Tente substituir por `Pilha p` e ao passá-lo como argumento, use `init(&p)` e `empty(&p)`. Aqui um exemplo: https://repl.it/@wldomiciano/Exemplo-em-C

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!